# Current, Previous and Next month calendar show in date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to find a date picker that looks similar to google analytics date picker:

[image]

Any idea if jQuery provides something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Twitter bootstrap styled date-range-picker is pretty close.

https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

[image]

There is also a [jQueryUI date range picker](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-UI-Date-Range-Picker) but it hasn't been updated in a while.